# Dell Inspiron/Windows 10

Tags: windows

I just purchased a new Dell Inspiron with Windows 10 and the only way I can find to shut it down is to close the lid. I have worked on computers for years and I was always told this created issues. Is this the proper shutdown for this computer with Windows?

Comment: What you are doing is simply putting the device to _Sleep_.  To properly shutdown you need to open the start menu, select `Power` then `Shutdown`.  I can post a walkthrough if you need one.

Comment: Hibernation might cause issues.. Sleep perhaps not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have changed default settings provided by your manufacturer, closing the lid most likely doesn't power off the system, it only puts it to sleep. When a system is sleeping, it's still powered on and ready to resume quickly. It's usually indicated by the power light blinking or glowing in a different color.

To power off the system completely:

1. Click the *Start* button

   [image: Screenshot showing the taskbar with a red arrow pointing at the Start button]
2. Click the power button

   [image: Screenshot showing taskbar with opened Start menu and a red arrow pointing at the Power button]
3. Click *Shut down*

   [image: Screenshot showing taskbar with opened Start menu and power menu, with *Shut down* item highlighted]

As @barlop noted in the comments, it's possible to configure Windows to shut down when the lid gets closed, but it's inconvenient for most users as it limits laptop's portability: you can't close the lid without losing your session. To change what happens when the lid is closed:

1. Right-click the battery icon in notification area of the taskbar (next to the clock), select *Power Options* from the menu that pops up.
2. In the left panel click *Change what closing the lid does*.
3. Configure options next to *When I close the lid* to your liking.

Comment: you wrote "http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Define-actions.png" <---  your first sentence is very inaccurate, for example, it might not be in sleep mode, it could be in hibernation mode. or shutdown, or still on  http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Define-actions.png

Comment: @barlop I have assumed that OP haven't changed that setting themselves  because it's harder to find than the power menu. Laptops are usually configured to sleep when the lid is closed out of the box, so I went with that.

Comment: -1 Your first sentence "Closing the lid doesn't power off the system, it only puts it to sleep. "  <-- is just plain wrong, or very inaccurate.  It doesn't matter whether you think the OP won't find other settings. That is no reason to say something that is wrong or very inaccurate. And it's not only the OP that would read your post. So you're not just giving them wrong or very inaccurate  information, but others as well.

Comment: @barlop edited.